# О "недобрых" людях

Tags: обсуждение

История такая.

На вопрос об  этимологии слова ***целоваться*** был дан ответ, за который участнику поставили минус. В ответе, как я понимаю,  он излагал собственную версию происхождения слова, а закончил его такой фразой: "Этимологические словари неубедительны".

Затем он добавил следующий **комментарий:**

Поразительно, **сколько в людях недоброты**, мало того, что моему собственному ответу поставили минус, так ещё и мой голос за этот ответ аннулировали. (Речь идет о сходном по содержанию ответе).

**Как разобраться в такой ситуации?**

["Целоваться" и "целое"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2890/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5)

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, тут нет существенной проблемы: участник дал ответ, который расходится с другими версиями, и это хорошо. Этот ответ подвергли критике, вследствие чего он имеет отрицательный рейтинг. Это не проявление недоброты, это как бы научная дискуссия, где вполне нормально ожидать критики.

Про аннулирование голосов не понимаю: насколько мне известно, этого не происходило.

Comment: А мне кажется, что проблема есть. Я случайно увидела этот комментарий и ответила на него. Я не знаю, правилен ли мой ответ. И тем более мало что знает и  понимает этот участник. Он-то считает, что все вокруг неправы. Аннулировать голос очень легко, надо просто кому-то поставить за положительный ответ свой минус, но он этого не знает. А еще он не знает, что подобные ответы обязательно получат минус, как бы интересно он ни доказывал свое мнение. Потому что никто не согласится с тем, что словари неубедительны. Так что ничего хорошего в этой ситуации я не вижу.

Comment: Такие ответы нужно как-то обозначать, например "моя версия: в чем я неправ". Тогда, может, кому-нибудь будет интересно найти ошибку в его рассуждениях. А главное, надо следить за порядком на форуме, чтобы у людей не оставалось плохого мнения о нас. Нужно сразу редактировать ответы новичков, если они составлены неверно,  помогать им. И следить,  чтобы не было нарушений дисциплины и т.п. Поэтому предлагаю организовать "патруль" или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: @Sharon спасибо за предложение! Давайте разбираться. 1) Ваш комментарий, увы, скорее всего, останется незамеченным. Предлагаю вам отправить его заново, добавив в начале @имяадресата; 2) Голос не аннулируется, он остается (можете щелкнуть на цифру, там будет статистика); 3) я не исключаю, что ответ остроумный и интересно обоснован, но мы все-таки занимаемся каким-никаким, но поиском истины, так что ошибки -- повод для минуса (но ох как хочется, чтобы давали комментарии с объяснением ошибок); 4) в смысле обозначать? чтобы сам отвечающий писал: «Это МОЕ мнение?» Так вроде бы многие уже делают...

Comment: 5) за порядком обязательно надо следить! обращайте, пожалуйста, наше (модераторов) внимание на то, что нужно с помощью тревоги — мы всё читаем и со всем стараемся разобраться; если вы считаете, что что-то пошло не так -- нужно создать вопрос на Мете; 6) редактировать ответы иногда действительно нужно (не меняя при этом основной мысли автора); будет замечательно, если вы станете одним из таких редакторов — у вас же очень большой опыт, вы имеете самое большое количество репутации на сайте!

Comment: 7) думаю, что что-то типа патруля вполне можно организовать, но для этого нужно изложить его цели и привлечь участников. Если у вас появится идея насчет этих моментов, создайте соответствующее обсуждение опять же на Мете (будет нужно — поставим метку [важное], чтобы привлечь внимание других участников). @Sharon

Comment: В той ситуации надо было сразу объяснить отношение на форуме к этимологическим вопросам. Что касается редактирования,то я в последнее время исправляю  плохо оформленные вопросы, но на постоянную нагрузку у меня времени не хватит, так как всё уходит на ответы. Может быть, в новом блоге  создать тему о постоянном контроле?

Comment: Да, Sharon правильно отметила: его голос не аннулировали, а свели на нет голосом против.

Answer (score 0):

Разобраться очень просто, было бы желание. А вот с этим как раз проблема.

Если считать, что все мнения имеют право на существование и при этом одинаково ценны, – тогда надо холить и лелеять таких участников, которые свысока бросают: "этимологические словари неубедительны", а потом обижаются за минус. Очевидно, что нынешняя политика модераторов к этому и сводится. Привлечь кого угодно, хотя бы и очевидных невежд!

Если же заботиться о качестве вопросов и ответов (то есть о качестве сайта!), то Просторечей надо банить пожизненно уже после пары-тройки подобных вопросов. Думаете, почему они приходят сюда? – а на приличные форумы им вход закрыт. Там нормальные модераторы. А нашим модераторам недостаточно даже сотни таких вопросов от Просторечей, на которые не получено ни единой реплики. Они считают это нормальным явлением. Печально.

Comment: Подписываюсь под каждым словом.